# Open bearings in a Schaublin 70?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

I would like to clean and change de belt in a Schaublin 70 Lathe, but when removing the main shaft, I noticed this weird bearings:

[image]

How would I remove it what should I take care about?

Comment: Why remove the bearings if you are only changing the belt? Remember: “if it ain’t broke don’t fix it”.

Comment: How do you change the belt when the only way to remove the belt is to remove the shaft? Plus I have to replace some parts that are broken...

Comment: Have you seen this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxr59DtuJda_UWxxT293Yl8ybDg/view